# How to specify image for the Settings app in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, image, settings, specs

How do I specify the image for the Setting in the iPhone for my iPhone app? What are the requirements for the images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In addition to the settings bundle, your application bundle can contain a custom icon for your application settings. If a file with the name Icon-Settings.png is located in the top of your application’s bundle directory, that icon is used to identify your application preferences in the Settings application. If no such image file is present, the Settings application uses your application’s icon file (Icon.png by default) instead, scaling it as necessary. Your Icon-Settings.png file should be a 29 x 29 pixel image.

From ["Application Preferences"](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationSettings/ApplicationSettings.html)

Comment: As SeanFang stated, you should use Icon-Small.png instead of Icon-Settings.png

Answer (score 3):

From the newest "iPhone Human Interface Guides", you should update your application bundle so that it contains only the "Icon-Small.png", instead of "Icon-Settings.png".

Answer (score 0):

And to add to Squeegy's comment -- the docs state that if you don't include an image file named Icon-Settings.png, it will use the icon.png from the app.  But there are times (Notifications screen) which actually don't default to the icon.png name, and you need to specify the name (icon.png) in your info.plist file.  Good practice to do it.